# unsigned int not work on project

Tags: c++, arduino, teensy

please help. I have old code for making analog synth and cant compile it on teensy 2.0, I use Arduino 1.6.9 and teensyduino 1.29
[Full code with errors](http://milkcrate.com.au/_other/downloads/teensy/SN76489_USB_MIDI_103/SN76489_USB_MIDI_103.ino)

Error log: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(uint8_t, unsigned int) {aka void (*)(unsigned char, unsigned int)}' to 'void (*)(uint8_t, int) {aka void (*)(unsigned char, int)}' [-fpermissive]

Mistake here, when use function: doBend;

```
void doBend(byte channel, unsigned int bend_usb) {
    byte chip_select = channel / 4; 
    channel = channel % 4;
    bendMSB = bend_usb >> 7; 
    bendLSB = bend_usb % B01111111; 
    if(channel >=0 && channel <= 2) {
       bend_MSB[channel + (chip_select * 4)] = bendMSB;
       bend_data[channel + (chip_select * 4)] = bend_MSB[channel + (chip_select * 4)];
       writeFrequency(pitchData[channel + (chip_select * 4)], channel, chip_select);
    }
}
```

Arduino don't know "unsigned int bend_usb".
I dont know c++ and need your help, how to fix this bug!

Comment: "I don't know what I'm doing; fix this for me" tends not to go over well on SO.

Comment: what function signature does `usbMIDI.setHandlePitchChange` expect for its argument?

Answer (score -1):

The issue  is probably related to this expression:
`usbMIDI.setHandlePitchChange(doBend);`

In this expression `doBend` behaves as a pointer to a function. Could you check the type of the parameter of the `setHandlePitchChange` function?

Comment: `int` would be casted automatically to an `unsigned int. Looks like the function signature doesn't match a desired function pointer signature.

Comment: That's true, I was editing my answer at the same time you respond me.

Comment: Now, your answer looks like it should be a comment. And yes, I know you can't comment yet.